# Replace all the different Placeholder with Class properties value

Tags: c#, string, reflection, formatting

I have a class as below

```
    public class Details
    {
        public string CreatedAt {set;get;)
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
     }
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public CustomerAddress Address { get; set; }
    }

    public class CustomerAddress
    {
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; } 
    }
```

and I have HTML file with HTML content and few placeholder. I am replacing placeholders as below.

```
  public static string ReplaceStringPlaceHolders(User Details)
        {
                 string MyHTML= File.ReadAllText(@"...Path");
                 //Replacing one by one
                 string newstring= MyHTML.
                .Replace("{created_at}", Details.CreatedAt)
                .Replace("{customer_info.address.line_1}", Details.Customer.Address.Line1)
                .Replace("{customer_info.address.line_2}", Details.Customer.Address.Line2)
                .Replace("{customer_info.address.city}", Details.Customer.Address.City)
                .Replace("{customer_info.address.state}", Details.Customer.Address.State)
                .Replace("{customer_info.address.postal_code}", Details.Customer.Address.PostalCode)
                .Replace("{customer_info.address.country}", Details.Customer.Address.Country)
            return newstring;

        }
```

but I don't like this way as I have put 50+ placeholders in my HTML file.
Is there a way that we can replace the placeholder when the placeholder name matches to class properties.

I am looking for something like this if possible:

```
MyHTML.replaceifPlaceHolderMatchesWithClassProperties(Label);
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: Just as a side note: instead of developing a templating function yourself, you could use an existing implementation, e.g. Liquid (https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/introduction/). There are various open source implementations for .NET. In addition to a greater function set, this is advisable also from a security point of view to avoid injecting dangerours HTML.

Comment: On the surface, it looks like you might want to consider MVC (ASP.Net Core MVC / ASP.Net MVC 5). With MVC, you would create a `ViewModel` based on your class(es) that you want to display on your pages, and then use Razor or similar to template the pages and display the properties of the view model. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Maybe take a look at [`FormatWith`](https://github.com/crozone/FormatWith)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can read properties with a help of *Reflection* and *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

....

private static string TryReadReflectionValue(object data, string name) {
  if (name == null)
    return null;

  foreach (string item in name.Replace("_", "").Trim('{', '}').Split('.')) {
    if (data == null)
      return null;

    var prop = data
      .GetType()
      .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | 
                     BindingFlags.Public)
      .Where(p => p.Name.Equals(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      .Where(p => p.CanRead)
      .Where(p => p.GetIndexParameters().Length <= 0)
      .FirstOrDefault();

    if (prop == null)
      return null;

    data = prop.GetValue(prop.GetGetMethod().IsStatic ? null : data);
  }

  return data?.ToString();
}
```

And match placeholders with a help of *regular expressions*:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

private static string MyReplace(string text, object data) {
  if (text == null)
    return text;  

  return Regex.Replace(
    text,
    @"\{\w._]+\}",
    match => TryReadReflectionValue(data, match.Value) ?? match.Value);
}
```

Usage:

```
public static string ReplaceStringPlaceHolders(User Details) {
  string MyHTML= File.ReadAllText(@"...Path");

  return MyReplace(text, Details); 
}
```

Here I assumed that

1. We always *drop* `_` in placeholders, e.g `{created_at}` corresponds to `CreatedAt` property
2. We *ignore case* in placeholders: `{created_at} == {Created_At} == {CREATED_at}` etc.
3. All placeholders are in `{letters,digits,_,.}` format

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you:

```
string MyHTML = "{PersonId}, {Name}, {Family}, {Age}";
Person p = new Person();
p.PersonId = 0;
p.Name = "hello";
p.Family = "world";
p.Age = 15;
var properties = typeof(Person).GetProperties().ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.GetType().GetProperties());
foreach (var item in properties)
    MyHTML = MyHTML.Replace("{" + item.Key.Name + "}", typeof(Person).GetProperty(item.Key.Name).GetValue(p).ToString());
Console.WriteLine(MyHTML);
```

output: `0, hello, world, 15`

Comment: Please note, that placeholders *can contain* `.` which means that we can have *nested* properties, e.g. `{customer_info.address.state}`

Comment: In this case, we can remove any `_`s and `.` between each `{}`. simply